# Externalize Tikz figures with pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, external-files

I want to externalize all figures I have created with Tikz in my document.
When I use the following code using TexShop 3.5 under OS X Yosemite 10.10.2,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \usetikzlibrary{external} 
 \tikzsetexternalprefix{tikz/} 
 \tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3.5,xscale=4.5]

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

an error message saying that the figure did not result in a usable output file ... .epsi, .eps, .ps is returned in the console.
The complete error log is:

```
    ./test.tex:16: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-er
ror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealj
ob{test}\input{test}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/test-figure
0' (expected one of .epsi:.eps:.ps:). Please verify that you have enabled syste
m calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also n
amed 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Err
or messages can be found in 'tikz/test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll 
try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Although I have created the folder "tikz" to host the files and entered "pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape" in the engine command line of TeXShop, the error is not fixed.
[image]

Can someone advise how to succeed externalizing the Tikz figure?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the images to EPS? Are you compiling the document with LaTeX (as opposed to pdfLaTeX)?

Comment: The output extension is not important, I just want to externalize them so I can compile my document faster. Additionally, I can have the capability to edit the ones I want. I am compiling the document with pdflatex as specified in the question.

Comment: Then remove the `pdftops` bit. Here's my setup for a `beamer` presentation: `\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{ffigurau/}
\tikzexternalize`. I don't even tell it the command to use - the default works fine for me. In some documents, I need an additional tweak, but I make adjustments if, and only if, I find I need them.

Comment: Note that the output extension *is* important. If you end up with an EPS image and you are compiling with pdfLaTeX, that needs to be converted (normally to PDF) before it can be used. (If you load, say, `graphicx`, this is what it does.) So it will then try to convert the EPS back to PDF, which is going to be messy at best.

Comment: @cfr When following your setup, the error remains.

Comment: I have updated the error log. I have used the address that corresponds to my directory.

Comment: OK. How are you compiling the main document? Are you using LaTeX? pdfLaTeX? Or...? If you are using LaTeX, then you will need to convert the image to postscript in order to use it and it may be that that is the part which is not working. Is the PDF file for the image created successfully?

Comment: I am using pdflatex to compile the document as stated in the question. No pdf file is created, rather a .md5 file appears.

Comment: Then stop telling it to convert the PDF to EPS format. You still have the `pdftops` line and TiKZ is still expecting postscript output. Also, I suggest again, trying with the defaults first rather than specifying the command line yourself.

Comment: The error you posted does not seem to correspond to the example code you posted anyway since it appears to be using an input file from a sub-directory. For testing, you need to test the code you are posting here.

Comment: I have updated the question without using subdirectory.

Comment: OK. Why is it still expecting postscript? `expected one of .epsi:.eps:.ps:`? Your example works fine here. But then, mine doesn't look for a postscript file. The only reason I can think it would do this is if you are compiling with LaTeX rather than pdfLaTeX. (Note: this is an issue of what you compile the main document with - not the command TiKZ uses to create the images.)

Comment: I don't know the source of the error, that is why I am asking to make it work.

Comment: I would compile from the command line so that you can be certain of the compilation command and so that you see the unfiltered console output. Run with `pdflatex -shell-escape` and nothing else so that you get interactive mode.

Comment: Like cfr I doubt that you are using pdflatex. Continue the compilation at the error by hitting enter and then check the end of the log-file. Does it say `Output written on XXX.pdf ..` or `Output written on XXX.dvi`?

Comment: It says Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 5512 bytes).

Comment: I have added in my question a picture of the preferences setup of my TeXShop

Comment: You are not compiling with pdfLateX. You are using LaTeX. LaTeX can only use postscript images (`.eps` etc.). That is why you are getting a `.dvi` rather than a `.pdf`. Try compiling at the command line, as I suggested. Or ensure you are using the pdfLaTeX engine in TeXShop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it will most probably be solved by the last comment.